# VOR GND Receiver checkpoint

Tags: vor, notam

KEUG currently has the following NOTAM

`!EUG 02/045 Mahlon Sweet Field, Eugene, OR (EUG) Navigation VOR ground receiver checkpoint unserviceable Feb 15, 2024 1750Z (10:50 PDT) to Mar 21, 2024 2000Z (13:00 PDT) Estimated`

Does that mean they cannot receive communication on VOR in case of lost comms? Is the VOR otherwise functional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A VOR ground receiver checkpoint is a place on the ground where you can check that your VOR receiver is working correctly. This NOTAM means that you can't use it. It has nothing to do with air navigation or lost communication procedures.

The VOR should otherwise be working properly, absent another NOTAM to the contrary. It's likely that construction is interfering with the signal at the checkpoint or something like that.